# Django, form.save(), doesn't save on the admin page

Tags: python, django, database, save

I don't know why the variables from the register form doesn't store in django admin page! I'm confused.  Thank you for read this, I really appreciate this. :)

//htmlsnippet.html

```
 {% block content %}
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<form  class ="site-form" action="register/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form}}

  <input type="submit" value="Signup">

</form>


{% endblock %}
```

//home.html

```
{% extends "register/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% include "register/includes/htmlsnippet.html" %}



{% endblock %}
```

//views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

    # Create your views here.

    def index(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect("/personal")
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'register/home.html',{'form':form})
```

well yeah because the form was in the website. the problem is that when I put in values in these input, it doesn't save in the admin.  this is my url for register  (

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^', views.index, name='index')#,url(r'^register', views.post, name='post')
               ]
```

")

this is my url pattern .

```
urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^register/$', include('register.urls'))
```

Comment: You have't shared your urlconf - are you sure `register/` corresponds to the `index` view you've shown?

Comment: well yeah because the form was in the website. the problem is that when I put in values in these input, it doesn't save in the admin.  this is my url for register  ( from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^', views.index, name='index')#,url(r'^register', views.post, name='post')
               ] ")



this is my url pattern . urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^register/$', include('register.urls'))
               ]

Comment: Don't explain things in comments -- make this part of the content with an [edit] to the question.

Comment: I did that now. it is just that , earlier it said I had too much text. but it works now...